# wrong results from simple java method

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I'm trying to write a program that asks for the size of an array of integers, the values of the array, and then finds the average of the positive integers and prints it. When I run it, I sometimes get wrong results. I haven't identified on what the wrong results depends but for example if I enter the following input: "array size: 4, array values: 1, 2, -5, 5" I get an average of "2.0"

Here's my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Mitra {

private static Scanner user_input;

double avg (int[] arr, int size)
{
    int sum = 0;
    int numbers = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<size;i++)
    {
        if (arr[i]>0)
        {
            sum = sum+arr[i];
            numbers++;
        }
        else{
            continue;
        }
    }
    double average = sum/numbers;
    return average;
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    user_input = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("enter array length");
    int alength = user_input.nextInt();
    int[] array_1 = new int[alength];
    for (int i=0; i<alength;i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter array value "+i);
        array_1[i] = user_input.nextInt();
    }
    Mitra obj = new Mitra();
    double result = obj.avg(array_1, alength);
    System.out.println("The average of the positive numbers of the array is "+result);
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
double average = sum/numbers;
```

to

```
double average = (double)sum/numbers;
```

to force floating point division.

Otherwise, int division (which is the operation that takes place when dividing two variables of int type) will give you 2 when dividing 8/3 (as you do in your example).

Comment: And don't forget to take care with the parentheses....

Answer (score 0):

When you evaluate `sum/numbers` it stores the result in a temporary variable(and the decimal part is already truncated) and then assigns it on the left side.You need to typecase it with (Double) like this:

```
double average = (double)sum/numbers;
```